# Jquery Bootstrap Pagination and also Search

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I created simple table in html page , where lots of data i want to use Jquery Bootstrap Pagination and Show data, how can i add bootstrap pagination and also search in this table, my html table code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>

<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Name</b></td>
    <td><b>Title</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Atish</td>
    <td>kumar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sandip</td>
    <td>Das</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rohit</td>
    <td>Sen</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Atul</td>
    <td>Sharma</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Moumita</td>
    <td>Sen</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nirmal</td>
    <td>Roy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Susmita</td>
    <td>Chatterjee</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shyam</td>
    <td>Das</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dipak</td>
    <td>Das</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Partha</td>
    <td>Sen</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sekhar</td>
    <td>Das</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gour</td>
    <td>Sen</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jotin</td>
    <td>Roy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shyam</td>
    <td>Das</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dipak</td>
    <td>Das</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Partha</td>
    <td>Sen</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write code for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the jQuery plugin [dataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) which is Bootstrap compatible and provides pagination and filtering.

Comment: when i used this code search button and pagination not come when run page